# Shakespeare Programming Language - errors while compiling

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, shakespeare-lang

To translate `hello.spl` to C, I run `./spl2c <hello.spl> hello.c` which works fine.

Next I run `gcc hello.c`, but I get this error:

> `fatal error: spl.h: No such file or directory`.

`spl.h` and `hello.c` are in the same directory.  I tried to change the include statement in `hello.c` from `#include <spl.h>` to `#include "spl.h"`, but then I get several errors when running `gcc hello.c` such as:

> `undefined reference to 'global_initialize'`
>
> `undefined reference to 'initialize_character'`

Could anyone tell me what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function global_initilize, initialize_character are declared but not define in hello.c. I think your program hello.c is depending on a library ("spl" library?) which is not included in your compile command.

You should have one of the following:

```
gcc hello.c whatever_file_who_define_undefined_function.c
gcc hello.c -lwhatever_lib_that_define_undefined_function.so
```

**EDIT :**

http://shakespearelang.sourceforge.net/report/shakespeare/#SECTION00070000000000000000
you need to include libspl.a library to make it work

So your compile option should be the following:

```
gcc hello.c -Ipath/to/spl/include/ -Lpath/to/spl/library -llibspl.a
```

- `-I` option to specify where your spl.h file is located
- `-L` option to specify where your libspl.a is located
- `-l` option to specify which library to use

or (*.a is static library, so it can be handle like a object file)

```
gcc hello.c -Ipath/to/spl/include/ path/to/spl/library/libspl.a
```

Comment: This is the command I type in, but I get the error "ld: library not found for -llibspl.a"

Comment: Got it working. What i had to do was run spl2c, then change the include statement in the hello.c file to include "spl.h" (IN QUOTES, NOT ANGLE BRACKETS). Then I ran gcc hello.c libspl.a, and finally ./a.out.

Comment: Actually, i dont get the problem with the include `"spl.h"` or `<spl.h>`. When you do a `<...>`, it first look on the system header file (like stdio.h etc...), if not found the compile look for local header file. There should be no problem, especially if `-I` option is specified...

Comment: Well if you get it working, then its cool. I am glad I could help :)